# How to disable pointerlock in aframe-extras?

Tags: aframe

I'm using @donmccurdy's checkpoint controls for movement in an aframe build. How can I disable the pointerlock from the script?

Comment: Solved it: added mouse-controls="pointerlockEnabled: false" to the a-camera tag

Answer (score 0):

> Solved it:
>
> Add mouse-controls="pointerlockEnabled: false" to the `a-camera` tag